# PL/SQL Using variables in an Explicit Cursor statement

Tags: plsql, cursor

I'm declaring an explicit cursor, however, I need to order the sql differently depending on user interaction.  The column to order by is passed to the procedure as a parameter, however, I'm having difficulty incorporating it into the sql for the cursor (as near as I can tell, it is interpreting the variable name as the name of the column and thus ordering by nothing.

Is there a way to use a locally declared variable in an explicit cursor statement?

Here's a basic skeleton of what I'm attempting thus far:

```
v_order_by varchar2(100) := <function that grabs URL param>
c_cursor is
select...
.
.
.
order by v_order_by;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  All the examples of using explicit cursors I've found so far are entirely unhelpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the possible values of v_order_by are static, you can do this:

```
order by case v_order_by
            when 'EMPNO' then empno
            when 'DEPTNO then deptno
            end
```

Otherwise you will need to use dynamic SQL and a ref cursor:

```
declare
   v_refcursor sys_refcursor;
   ...
begin
   open v_refcursor for   
     'select...
     order by ' || v_order_by;
```

If you do that, be sure to learn how to use bind variables rather than literals in your dynamic SQL where clause.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Unfortunately, it seems that case statements require all the possible values to be the same type.  This doesn't work for me since I have several columns that need to be sorted like numbers and others that need to be sorted like Strings.  I ended up changing everything to a ref cursor.

Thanks again.

Comment: You *can* sort strings and numbers together, you just need to convert the numbers to strings, e.g. TO_CHAR(mynum,'fm00000000') will left-pad integers with zeroes so that they are ordered correctly when sorted alphabetically.